# Version Management in Sharepoint checkin

Tags: ios, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

While performing the checkin in sharepoint my file version is getting updated by 0.2 but it should be 0.1.

This is happening because after checkin i am uploading the edited file again which further increase the version number by 0.1.

How i can prevent the version update in case of uploading the edited file?.

i have used below method and in both case version is getting updated

**case 1** /_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('%@')/Files/add(url='%@',overwrite=true)
Method:POST
body:content of file

**case 2**
/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('%@')/$value
Method:POST
body:content of file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try check out/check in ?

First Check out your document. 
Do all your update (field values, content of file)
After all your update, check in (major or minor version)

Your version should be upgrade once (you create new version when you check out only visible by you, you can work on you doc, when you check in the version is validate and all users can see it)